# Android internet connection problem on sleep mode?

Tags: android, httpwebrequest, connection, sleep, wakelock

I have a service Activity and a thread in it. Problem is when phone go to sleep mode, thread doesnt send http request And i check the network state if it is not connect i work to connect it but i get "Permission denial: writing to secure settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" error. But i already put the permission tag in AndroidManifest.xml. I also try this:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK , "TAG");
wl.acquire();
```

But it is not solve my problem. phone Already go to sleep mode. Here is my checkNetwork code:

```
private boolean checkNetwork(){
    try{
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(info == null){
            connectivity.setNetworkPreference(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
            int status = connectivity.startUsingNetworkFeature(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE, "cmwap");
            NetworkInfo info1 = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return false;
        }
        if (info.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED )
            return true;
        return false;

    }catch(Exception ex){
        return false;
    }
}
```

public class MainActivity extends Service {
.....

```
private Runnable httpThread = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
//i send http request here
}
}
```

Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though your application requested `android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, it does not mean this permission will be granted to your application in runtime.

In fact, for this particular permission (`android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`) to be granted, your application must be signed with System certificate. And only vendor of the device can usually do that (for production devices).

Comment: so is it not possible for me? what can i do? My application doesnt request in sleep mode_?

Comment: In most general case your application cannot control connectivity. It can only react when connectivity is available or lost. It's Android's and User's business to allow networking when in sleep mode or not.

Comment: so why my phone go to sleep mode ? i already use power manager and wake lock classes. How to i allow networking in sleep mode?